# OpenLayers 3 Geoserver GeoWebCache WMS tile alignment issue

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, wms, tiles, geowebcache

I've started moving to OpenLayers 3 - very nice. One issue I have is with the dynamic tile size sent to my Geoserver - which is often 333.

This doesn't line up with the cache (which is 256 for EPSG:900913) so the Geoserver has to build a new tile - somewhat slow ...

Sometimes I get 256 (e.g. from Firefox on Linux) but usually it's off (e.g. Chrome on Linux, Android, Safari on iOS).

I've looked at a number of questions on this site, and have gleaned that I might need to set a tileGrid, but how do I do this?

Do I need to set resolutions on my map?

Here's my code:

```
var wms =   new ol.layer.Tile({
  source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
    url: '/geoserver/wms',
    params: {'LAYERS': 'test:wms_layer', 'TILED': true, },
    serverType: 'geoserver'
  })
});

var osm = new ol.layer.Tile({
  source: new ol.source.OSM()
});

var map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    layers: [
      osm,
      wms,
    ],
    view: new ol.View({
      center: ol.proj.transform([11.953, 57.757,], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
      zoom: 16,
    })
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be using GeoWebCache (GWC) in [direct integration mode](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/geowebcache/using.html#direct-integration-with-geoserver-wms) which is known to have issues with OpenLayers as noted in the documentation. You will get better results using GWC in [TMS or WMTS mode](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/geowebcache/using.html#geowebcache-endpoint-url) where you use a URL of the form:

```
http://example.com/geoserver/gwc/service/wms
```

instead of

```
http://example.com/geoserver/wms
```

Comment: Thanks @iant. I tried the code with '/geoserver/gwc/service/wms' as suggested, but get a 400 error. Do I need to disable direct integration mode for this to work?

Comment: no it should just work - look at the address on any of the links to wmts, tms or wms-c on your geoserver home page to see what it should be

Comment: Hm. @iant Very strange - this works: 'http://localhost/geoserver/gwc/service/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=getcapabilities&TILED=true'. Is it not easier to force OpenLayers to line up with the gridset on the GWC?

Comment: I doubt it - just use a WMTS layer and it all works

Comment: ok. @iant am I right in understanding that, if I can get the GWC to work on /geoserver/gwc/service/wms, then I shouldn't need to change the above OpenLayers code to get the right grid alignment?

Comment: provided you are using a standard tileset it should be fine otherwise you need to tell openlayers about the tile set scheme

Comment: Thanks @iant - just need to get rid of this 400 error now, so I can try this :)

Comment: probably need to ask a new question with the error message

Comment: Maybe a new question @iant - I now have /geoserver/gwc/service/wms working, but get the error from GWC: "400: The requested tile dimensions 250x250 do not match those of the grid set (256x256)"? I've noticed this OL3 example (https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/wms-custom-tilegrid-512x256.html) does some tileGrid stuff, is that what I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, sorted it now - thanks to @iant :)
By using the /geoserver/gwc/service/wms endpoint and following this example: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/wmts-layer-from-capabilities.html, I changed my code to:

```
var parser = new ol.format.WMTSCapabilities();
fetch('/geoserver/gwc/service/wmts?REQUEST=getcapabilities').then(function(response) {
    return response.text();
  }).then(function(text) {
    var result = parser.read(text);
    var options = ol.source.WMTS.optionsFromCapabilities(result,
      {layer: 'test:wms_layer', matrixSet: 'EPSG:900913'});
    var wms  = new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.WMTS(options)
    });
    map.addLayer( wms );
});
```